# Interface definiton and port typing with SysML/UML

Tags: interface, uml, port, protocols, sysml

I would like to describe services as components with their ports and interfaces. It should become clear by the description, what functionalities are provided, and how to utilize them.

In my understanding, I can type a port either with this notation `<name>:<type>`, where the type can be specified by an interface block? Or using the "lollipop", where the interface type is specified by the name of the "lollipop"?

[image]

Now, I would like to see what application or transportation protocol is utilized by a interface/port, to get an idea on how to connect to it. But I don't know what is the best way to do so. I thought about two ways.

First: specifying the protocol (here TCP/IP) by the port type and the interface (provided information) by the "lollipop" notation.

[image]

Second: specifying a transportation/application protocol as the base interface of an application specific interface.

[image]

I really don't know if any of that makes sense or if there is a better way to describe that. Please let me know.

***EDIT:***

Based on the answer of qwerty_so, I understand that the generalization of an interface from a protocol is wrong. But to indicate the utilized protocol, it should be specified by the port type? Based on that, I made another representation of two components (this time in UML, i hope it doesn't cause any confusion). Each component provides the same interface through a varied port. Basically it is the same as the first notation, extendet by the `realize` relation from the lollipop to the interface. The first component utilizes a basic `TCP/IP` and the second a `gRPC` protocol in order to realize the `Interface1`.

[two components with different port types and same interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsOuV.png)

Is that a more accurate way to represent the interface and its realization by a specific protocol?

Is the `realize` relation necessary, because shouldn't it be clear by the interface name?

Answer (score 0):

`TCP/IP` is a protocol. And that's what is used for the port. Draw a `realize` relation from the port towards the interface.

The `interface1` is the software interface. So draw a `realize` relation from the lollipop towards that.

Your lowest design would be wrong since interface and protocol are two very different things.

I always think of a port a a plug bundling a number of (SW) interfaces. In SysML terms it also extends to power supply as interface (which for pure soft-workers is kind of strange ;-).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited the question, because I'm still not quite sure about it. Is the ``realize`` relation really necessary?

Comment: Instead of using `realize` you could type it as you did. However, I think of "realizing" a protocol on a port as what comes to mind first.